PostgreSQL 13 logical replication keeps dying
For some time now I keep facing the same issue on PostggreSQL 13.14 cluster - there are 6 replication slots, 5 for one client server (different tables, same target db) one for other client (some tables overlap with other publications).
Replication works fine until all slots stops at the same restart LSN:

After that I see lag growing until it goes out of max_slot_wal_keep_size and it needs to be dropped and recreated.

There are no old sessions.
No locks on database.
No orphaned prepared prepared transactions.
I see no errors on both subscribers and source db.

After replication is resynchronized it works fine for some time until the same issue happens. Datase is regularly vacuumed (vacuum freez, plus full once a month).
I have no idea why it keeps happening. Db runs on VM in OpenShift cluster using RedHat 8.9

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It would be useful to have more information about this issue like:


Do you have something in the log files? (Database and OS log files)


What is happening in the database when it stops?


Is there any specific query running at that time? Any specific task on the OS?


Unfortunately, without more information, it's hard to know why it’s failing.
